# Prove $(a+b+c-3)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-3\right)+abc+\frac{1}{abc}\ge 2.$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For any positive real numbers $a,b,c$ then prove $$(a+b+c-3)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-3\right)+abc+\frac{1}{abc}\ge 2.$$
I've try to assume $a+b+c\ge 3.\quad(1)$

By AM-GM $$abc+\frac{1}{abc}\ge 2$$ and we need to prove $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-3\ge 0$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge \frac{9}{a+b+c}$$but $$\frac{9}{a+b+c}\ge 3 \iff a+b+c\le 3$$ which gives a contradiction to $(1).$

Similarly when $a+b+c<3$ I can not find a good approach for each assumed condition.

Could you please give some hint to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since among three numbers: $$(a-1)(bc-1), (b-1)(ca-1), (c-1)(ab-1)$$there are at least two of them having the same sign. WLOG, assume that they are $(b-1)(ca-1)$, and $(c-1)(ab-1)$.

We have:
$$ \left(a+b+c -3\right) \left(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{c} -3\right) +abc +\frac{1}{abc} -2$$

$$= \left( a+\frac{1}{a}-2\right) \left(b+\frac{1}{b} +c+\frac{1}{c}-4 \right)+\frac{(b-1)(c-1)(ab-1)(ac-1)}{abc} \ge 0.$$

Comment: Very nice. Can you find a SOS solution? (I tried but no success yet.)

Comment: @RiverLi I found [one](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kMFuhDAMRO9I_EOOjrMBkT33uLf-hO0CXakUBCuV_fvaWUhPPSB5Zh7R2MM6T257TsuzIRZ3n5Z5fTi6OL44qauhxGf0RY9-PwMa-2a6b9Jk90TeTdz2Za0rBd2bA0IOjBIEKSRUheIRgAIHiVcdu5ZC17J-pkMmVMALjcnX1agPEQLHziMmBHkNLjguAoGKK0WUn9QFNkOsjQ6hi9ejzMG2ZJBlWlXrnpCOvrzTskGW5b0ya5C29aVLKwpZo7xkisfWmOwqdbV9zj9QLgX5gDB47_-Jxr-o3xf6_oAhqvcLEGR0xg==&lang=python&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), however I didn't really enjoy it. It is complicated.

Comment: @RiverLi I realized that the original inequality is surprisingly reduced to $(xy+yz+zx+xyz)^2 \ge xyz(x+y+z)$, where $x=a-1,...$ You may have a nice SOS identity?

Comment: Wow, very nice SOS. Nice observation.

Comment: From your SOS, I notice it is the form of $g_1 f_1^2 + g_2f_2^2 + \cdots$ where $g_k$ is non-negative but may not be a SOS. I didn't realize this. This is why SOStools fail to find SOS because it want to find $h_1^2 + h_2^2 + \cdots$

Comment: I found that SOStools can found real SOS of $(a + b + c)(2abc + ab + bc + ca)f(a,b,c)$ (letting $a = x_1^2, b = x_2^2, c = x_3^2$). Your term $2abc + ab + bc + ca$ is very nice.

Comment: @BabyLE Hello KaiRain.

Answer (score 5):

*Here is a proof.*

Let $p = a + b, q = ab$. Then $p^2 \ge 4q$.

The desired inequality is written as
$$(p + c - 3)\left(\frac{p}{q} + \frac{1}{c} - 3\right) + qc + \frac{1}{qc} \ge 2$$
or
$$\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3 + q\right) c + \left(p - 3 + \frac{1}{q}\right)\frac{1}{c}
\ge 1 - (p - 3)\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3\right). \tag{1}$$

Using $p^2 \ge 4q$, we have $\frac{p}{q} -3 + q \ge 
\frac{\sqrt{4q}}{q} - 3 + q
= \frac{(\sqrt{q} + 2)(\sqrt{q} - 1)^2}{\sqrt{q}} \ge 0$,
and $p - 3 + \frac{1}{q} \ge p - 3 + \frac{1}{p^2/4} 
= \frac{(p + 1)(p - 2)^2}{p^2} \ge 0$. By AM-GM and (1), it suffices to prove that
$$2\sqrt{\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3 + q\right) \cdot \left(p - 3 + \frac{1}{q}\right)}
\ge 1 - (p - 3)\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3\right). \tag{2}$$

We only need to prove the case that
$1 - (p - 3)(\frac{p}{q} - 3) \ge 0$. From (2), it suffices to prove that
$$4\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3 + q\right) \cdot \left(p - 3 + \frac{1}{q}\right)
\ge \left(1 - (p - 3)\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3\right)\right)^2$$
or
$$\frac{(p - 1 - q)^2}{q}\left(1 - (p - 3)\left(\frac{p}{q} - 3\right)\right)
+ \frac{(p - 1 - q)^2}{q}\left(p + \frac{p}{q} - 4\right) \ge 0$$
which is true, using $p + p/q - 4 \ge p + p/(p^2/4) - 4 = \frac{(p - 2)^2}{p} \ge 0$.

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

Here we need to assume that $a,b,c>0$, and this condition will be used later in this proof.

Since we have the inequality

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$$

with $''=''$ iff $a=b=c$, we get

$$(a+b+c-3)(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} -3) + abc + \frac{1}{abc}$$

$$\geq (3\sqrt[3]{abc} - 3)(3\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} - 3) + abc + \frac{1}{abc} \cdots (*) $$

$$= 9(t-1)(\frac{1}{t} -1 ) + t^3 + \frac{1}{t^3}$$

$$= t^3 + \frac{1}{t^3} - 9(t + \frac{1}{t}) + 18$$

where $t = \sqrt[3]{abc}$.

And then, since

$$(t+\frac{1}{t})^3 = t^3 + \frac{1}{t^3} + 3(t+ \frac{1}{t})$$

we have

$$t^3 + \frac{1}{t^3} - 9(t + \frac{1}{t}) + 18$$

$$= (t+\frac{1}{t})^3 - 3(t+ \frac{1}{t})- 9(t + \frac{1}{t}) + 18$$

$$= (t+\frac{1}{t})^3 -12(t+ \frac{1}{t}) + 18$$

Let $x = t+\frac{1}{t} \geq 2$ with $''=''$ iff $t = 1$, and set

$$f(x) = x^3 - 12x + 18$$

we have

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 - 12$$

and we can see that when $x \geq 2$, $f'(x) \geq 0$, and this means $f(x)$ is increasing when $x \geq 2$. So we have

$$f(x) \geq f(2) = 2^3 - 12\times 2 + 18 = 2$$

Thus, if $a,b,c$ are positive, then we finally get

$$(a+b+c-3)(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} -3) + abc + \frac{1}{abc} \geq f(x) \geq f(2) = 2$$

with $''=''$ iff $a=b=c=1$.

$\textbf{Note:}$ As @Helloworld and @Macavity have mentioned in the comments, there is a big jump to verify why we can do $(*)$. My plan is to somehow show $a,b,c$ have to be within $[0,1]$ then it will be good. Hope someone can continue the work together.

Comment: the application of AM-GM requires both factors positive?

Comment: When you say $(a+b+c-3)(1/a+1/b+1/c-3) \ge (3\sqrt[3]{abc}-3)(\frac3{\sqrt[3]{abc}}-3)$, implicitly you're considering the terms in parenthesis to be also non-negative...  Consider $a=b=c=2$ for e.g.

Comment: @Macavity Yes, I implied it.

Comment: @Helloworld  Yes, I know that it is not quite true if I assume $(a+b+c-3)(\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} -3) + abc + \frac{1}{abc} \geq (3\sqrt[3]{abc} - 3)(3\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{abc}} - 3) + abc + \frac{1}{abc}$, so I am still thinking about how to fix this

Comment: @Macavity I know, but I also have no idea how to fix this. Maybe we can somehow argue that $a,b,c$ have to be within $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Yimin No, not necessarily. Here I assume $a,b,c$ to be positive, because, $t + \frac{1}{t}$ doesn't have minimum if $t<0$, and $t = \sqrt[3]{abc}$, so $\sqrt[3]{abc}$ has to be positive, and this means either all of them are positive or 2 negative and 1 positive. To show the result more easily, I without loss of generality assume that all of them are positive.

Comment: @ZYX When does equality hold?